# IIS Site breaks after disabling SSLv3

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl, iis-7.5, tls, poodle

I am trying to disable SSLv3 on a 2008 R2 web server that runs IIS 7.5 but as soon as I disable SSLv3 and reboot, the website is no longer reachable.  I ran a packet capture with SSLv3 still enabled and my client is establishing a TLS 1.2 connection so I don't understand why disabling SSLv3 breaks the site.

I am not the strongest with encryption but know the basics so any insight as to what my be causing this issue is appreciated.  Below is the PoSH script that I ran (the SSLv3 Reg keys I changed to a value of 1 to bring the site back online):

```
# Add and Enable TLS 1.0 for client and server SCHANNEL communications
md 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0' -Force
md 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force

# Add and Enable TLS 1.1 for client and server SCHANNEL communications
md 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1' -Force
md 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server' -Force
md 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client' -name 'Enabled' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force

# Add and Enable TLS 1.2 for client and server SCHANNEL communications
md 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2' -Force
md 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -Force
md 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -name 'Enabled' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force

# Disable SSL 2.0 (PCI Compliance)
md 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
md 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force


# NOTE: If you disable SSL 3.0 then you may lock out some people still using
# Windows XP with IE6/7. Without SSL 3.0 enabled, there is no protocol available
# for these people to fall back. Safer shopping certifications may require that
# you disable SSLv3.
#
# Disable SSL 3.0 (PCI Compliance) and enable "Poodle" protection
md 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
md 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Client' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Client' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force


Write-Host 'After the system has been rebooted you can verify your server configuration at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/'
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'A computer restart is required to apply settings. Restart computer now?'
Restart-Computer -Force -Confirm
```

Comment: Hmm.. is the 443 listening port still open with SSLv3 is disabled?  If so, then maybe do a packet capture and see where in the SSL process it's failing?

Comment: I'm with @ShaneMadden on this one-- we need to see what's happening when you've got SSLv3 disabled. A packet capture of the failing state would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks gents.  I plan to do just as suggested but will need to wait until I am allowed to take down the site again to run the test which likely won't be until after the holiday.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Go to IIS and Edit Bindings of your website.
Remove the https binding and then re enter it.
It will work again.

I hope this helps you.